# Sort NSMutableArray memory leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray, nssortdescriptor

My object has a private NSMutableArray items. I am using the following code to sort the objects in items in size order:

```
-(void)sortItems{
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"size" ascending:YES];    
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSMutableArray* newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: sortedArray];
[self setItems:newArray];
[sortDescriptor release];
```

}

Obviously this is a memory leak here, because every time I call sortItems, I am allocing new memory and assigning items to point to it. I've tried releasing the old memory as follows:

```
NSMutableArray* newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: sortedArray];
NSMutableArray* oldArray = [self items];
[self setItems:newArray];
[oldArray release];
```

But that gives an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. I've read up on memory handling in objC, and I'm convinced I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Show the implementation/declaration of your `setItems` method.  That *should* be retaining `newArray` meaning you need to `[newArray release]` immediately after calling it.

Comment: at the moment items is property: 
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableArray *items; I guess I need to read up on when to use 'retain' in the property flags!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're leaking the new array, not the old one:

```
NSMutableArray* newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: sortedArray];
[self setItems:newArray];
[sortDescriptor release];
[newArray release]; // <-- add this
```

The fundamental rule is that you must release anything that you have allocated, and you normally shouldn't care about keeping things retained for anyone (i.e. `[self setItems:]`), those who need something retained will do it themselves.

I would also recommend making `self.items` a mutable array, and using `[self.items sortUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptor` to sort inplace without creating a copy.

Comment: great! thanks very much. should the property flags of items be set to retain, rather than assign?

Comment: @JimmyB I assumed they already are. Yes, for this use case, they should be. If your object is the owner of the array, it is the one to retain the array.

Comment: this looks like it should work, but for some reason adding this [newArray release] crashes the app even before it hits this function... very strange!

Comment: @JimmyB It means there are problems somewhere else. Show how the old value of `items` was assigned, and places where it is released/autoreleased if any.

Comment: thanks, I will look into this! the sortItems seems to be running successfully a number of times, so you're right - the problem must be elsewhere. thanks for your help!

Comment: thank you for your help. as it turns out, my init function for tiles was setting items = .., rather than self.items = ...
 thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you cannot release the newArray in your first example?

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"size" ascending:YES];    
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [items sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
NSMutableArray* newArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray: sortedArray];
[self setItems:newArray];
[newArray release];
[sortDescriptor release];
```